# custom camera launch on button click in android

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera, imagebutton, eclipse-luna

I want to open a my custom camera when i click on a button in my app.
Please help me out.

Thanks in Advance:)

```
private static Button button;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    OnClickButtonListener();
}

public void OnClickButtonListener() {
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.camerabutton);
button.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent =new Intent ("com.example.hrbl.camera");
                startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Comment: So is the custom camera another app? Or is it in an activity inside this app?

Comment: its a activity inside the app. ,

Answer (score 0):

If it's an activity inside the app then try this

```
 Intent intent =new Intent (MyAcitivty.this, CustomCameraActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Just change the activity names so they fit yours